# Best practices for a widget API in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

I am currently making an app that allows third-party developers to create widgets for it using the API. Right now, I ship a library with the application containing a class that developers must create a subclass of. They must package their program in an NSBundle for my app to load.

Have you ever created an Objective-C APIs? If so, do you have tips to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to provide documentation for your API I would suggest you to use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). [Here](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/) you'll find an interesting tutorial on how to document with doxygen.

I would also recommend you reading [API Design](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/) by Matt Gemmell. It's a good reference on what a developer could expect from a well designed API.